# How do I use the Freestyle SVG Exporter to reproduce the examples in the documentation?

Tags: export, freestyle, svg

If I understand correctly from [the severely short documentation page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/render_freestyle_svg.html), the Freestyle SVG exporter can export a model to a SVG file using different styles:

-a series of volumetric lines, as seen here:

[image]

-outlines where the hidden edges are rendered as dotted lines, as seen here:

[image]

However, the documentation doesn't bother expanding on how these results were achieved. There are no modifiers in the Modifiers Panel, or in the Freestyle Export Panels, that seem to correspond to these examples (I looked in both 2.79 and 2.80).

**How does one render 3D models into SVG, while applying the styles of these examples?**

Comment: An example for the dotted lines can be found in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159028/scientific-illustration-non-photorealistic-rendering-of-sparse-wireframe-with-d/159038#159038). Note that you don't have to use edge marks if you want all edges to be drawn. The line styles are created by setting up *FreeStyle Line Sets*. The exporter just outputs the result as SVG file, it does not configure the appearance except for  stroke cap style and fill contours.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it. I guess I've just spent 4 hours trying to understand what settings to select to get the results in the first image from the Freestyle Line Sets and nothing I try works. The documentation doesn't help. Just wasting my time trying to click all the buttons and getting infuriated. Are the strokes in the picture of Suzanne all actual edge loops?

Comment: No, the lines in the first image do not follow the edge loops, Suzannes topology is different. The creation was explained in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114345/blender-freestyle-vertical-lines?rq=1).

Comment: I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BMXlOV2ugE) which is short and sweet and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ji06I_KalEw) which explains how to export SVG including the fill and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfmdUaTPySc) which talk about export animations in SVG.