# How is the demo image for "Freestyle SVG Exporter" in the Blender manual made?

Tags: rendering, freestyle, svg, vector

[On the page for Freestyle SVG Exporter](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/render/render_freestyle_svg.html), there's a demo image with 2 monkey head with Freestyle stripes. How could those stripes be made?

[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/114417/29586

Comment: If you want to do it without Freestyle you could easily do it with Wave Texture and b&w ColorRamp

Comment: @moonboots It has to be Freestyle, so I can export an SVG with that addon.